# Lucido's three prime lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I am looking for  proof of this statement I encountered in a paper.

$\textbf{(Lucido’s Three Primes Lemma)}$- Let $G$ be a finite solvable group. If $p, q, r $ are distinct primes dividing |$G$|, then $G$ contains an element of order the product of two of these three primes.

I could not go much further with this. Any hint or references please.

Comment: Also on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186195/lucidos-three-prime-lemma